# BLINK CHARACTER ON LCD

Tags: c, arduino, lcd

I have small question Here . I have 16x2 lcd that being interface with arduino.In below blink i can blink the cursor , But i wanted to blink number instead of cursor. How to do here with arduino.
[Keypad shield used](http://www.freetronics.com/pages/16x2-lcd-shield-quickstart-guide#.Uv9jb87pegI)
i wanted to blink date variable above . how to do it

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 7, 6, 5, 4);
int Blink_pos[6][2]={
  {
    5,0  }
  ,
  {
    8,0  }
  ,
  {
    11,0  }
  ,
  { 
    5,1  }
  ,
  { 
    8,1  } 
  , 
  {
    11,1  }                          
}; 
enum _Screen_edit_item
{ 
  EDIT_DAY,
  EDIT_MONTH,
  EDIT_YEAR, 
  EDIT_HOUR,
  EDIT_MINUTE, 
  EDIT_SEC
};
typedef enum _Screen_edit_item EDIT_SCREEN_ITEM;
static int local_day=1;
static int local_month=3;
static int local_year=2014;
int local_s=12;
static int local_h=23;
static int local_m=1;
void setup(){ 
  lcd.begin(16,2); 
  lcd.clear(); 
} 

void loop()
{   
  Blink_LCD(); 
}  
void Blink_LCD(){ 
  int j=0;
  for(int j=0; j<6;j++)
  {
    digitalClockDisplay(); 
    lcd.setCursor(Blink_pos[j][0],Blink_pos[j][1]);
    Serial.print(Blink_pos[j][0]); 
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.println(Blink_pos[j][1]); 

    delay(300); 
    switch(j)
{
case EDIT_DAY: 
  lcd.print(local_day); goto LABEL;
  break;
case EDIT_MONTH:
  lcd.print(local_month); goto LABEL; 
  break;
case EDIT_YEAR:
  lcd.print(local_year); goto LABEL; 
  break;
case EDIT_HOUR:
  lcd.print(local_h);  goto LABEL;
  break;
case EDIT_MINUTE:
  lcd.print(local_m); goto LABEL; 
  break;
case EDIT_SEC:
  lcd.print(local_s);  goto LABEL;
  break;

}
LABEL: lcd.setCursor(Blink_pos[j][0],Blink_pos[j][1]);
      lcd.print("_");
      delay(300);
      }

}
void digitalClockDisplay()
{ 
  Serial.print(local_s);

  lcd.begin(16,2);
  lcd.setCursor(0,0); 
  lcd.print("Date:");
  if((local_day>0) &&(local_day<10) )
  {  
    lcd.print("0");  
    lcd.print(local_day);
  }
  else{ 
    lcd.print(local_day);
  }  
  lcd.print("/");
  if((local_month>0) &&(local_month<10) )
  {   
    lcd.print("0");  
    lcd.print(local_month);
  }
  else{   
    lcd.print("0");  
    lcd.print(local_month);
  }  
  lcd.print("/"); 
  lcd.print(local_year);
  lcd.print("    ");  
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);   
  lcd.print("Time:");
  if((local_h>0) &&(local_h<10) ){   
    lcd.print("0");  
    lcd.print(local_h);
  }
  else{ 
    lcd.print(local_h); 
  }  
  lcd.print(":"); 
  if((local_m>0) &&(local_m<10) ){   
    lcd.print("0");  
    lcd.print(local_m);
  }
  else{ 
    lcd.print(local_m); 
  }  
  lcd.print(":");
  if((local_s>0) &&(local_s<10) ){   
    lcd.print("0");  
    lcd.print(local_s);
  }
  else{ 
    lcd.print(local_s); 
  } 
  lcd.print("    ");
}
```

Comment: do you want to print and blink the number on the second line(1st line ="enter password") of the LCD ?? or simply print any number and keep blinking it ?

Comment: The best answer is: DON'T DO THAT. From a usability perspective this is a horrible thing to do. LCD screens suck and if you don't look from the correct angle they suck even worse. Don't make it even worse by blinking text. Since this isn't actually an answer I'd select Ignacios' answer.

Comment: What you would suggest.i have array .these array should bet stored with value display on Screen. i wanted to see what is there in array element

Comment: Well, because you only have 2 lines to work with. You'll want a menu system. Think of a business class printer setup menu. This is the most functional way to interface with one of these types of LCD screen.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your code. Where do `Enter_Array`, `j`, and `i` get declared?

Comment: Well, I've GTG but let me just give you one hint. Make a function which draws a string of text on the top line. Then make a set of functions for each type of value you'd like to show on the second line. For each of those handle any input they specifically use. Then in your loop it becomes a simple matter of calling the right second row display function or switching the entire page. This will allow you to make complex menus without your code getting more complex.

Comment: i need simple code where i can store data into array one by one when up key pressed . and select key to save data and finally display all data on lcd

Answer (score 2):

Alternate between displaying the number and displaying spaces at the appropriate locations.

Comment: i could not understand

Comment: Go to the position. Display the number. Delay. Go to the position. Display spaces. Delay. Repeat.

Comment: i have done as you said. But in**digitalClockDisplay()** i am saying that if no is less than 9. lcd.print 0 and variable . So when switch function called and postion is @5 printing 5 instead of 05

Answer (score 1):

USE lcd.display();      and lcd.noDisplay();
in a loop to make the text blink for while using delay function

Comment: using delay() funtion its not recommended